# Adding an bundle in Appkernel on symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have a requirement for which i need to install Zetawebmailbundle in the vendor page, I tried to make an entry in the AppKernel file, but its showing error as class not found.

new SimpleThings\ZetaWebmailBundle\SimpleThingsZetaWebmailBundle()

FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'SimpleThings\ZetaWebmailBundle\SimpleThingsZetaWebmailBundle' not found in /home/check/Projects/Webparse/app/AppKernel.php line 30

Comment: How did you download the bundle? Manually? Via Composer?

Comment: I did it manually via git clone..which puts the actual realted files to vendor/bundles/SimpleThings/zetawebmailBundle/ et.../

Answer (score 0):

The bundle that you are trying to use doesnt seem to have a composer friendly repo. This means that you have 2 options.

1) You can follow their install instructions here: https://github.com/simplethings/ZetaWebmailBundle

or 2) You can fork their repository and create your own composer.json

with option 2 you will need to download the ez Components which you can find here: http://ezcomponents.org/ and add that to your forked repository and your composer.json. This option will probably take a lot more time and maybe even some trial and error. I recommend that you just follow the install instructions in option 1.

Edit: Scrapped my original answer for this one.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Let me try this quickly and see if it works

Comment: Chauuser, It doesnt seems to work. I got stuck in this for almost 2 days, Any suggestions or help in this regard will be of great help

Comment: Looks like this was a little more complex than i thought. however the bundle that you are trying to use comes with pretty detailed install instructions did you try and follow them? https://github.com/simplethings/ZetaWebmailBundle

Comment: I tried option 1, followed the instructions what they had provided in the installation doc. But i couldnt autoload neither in app/autoload.php nor in composer.json.

Comment: I could probably take some more time and provide some more instructions for step 2. But before i do that why are you not just using swiftmailer?